# Internal Server Error when calling ajax post method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing problem with calling ajax POST method, it just returns error with message: Internal Server Error.

My script looks like this:

```
$('.add-column').click(function () {

    var ids = [];

    $('#table1 > tbody > tr.selected').each(function () {

        var ident = $(this).attr('id');
        ids.push(ident);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Syzyf/AddUserColumns',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id : JSON.stringify(ids) },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

And controller's method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUserColumns(List<int> ids)
{ 
    var userId = GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

    using (var ctx = new SyzyfContext())
    {
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            var uc = new UserColumns();
            uc.ColumnId = id;
            uc.UserId = userId;

            ctx.UserColumns.Add(uc);
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json("Success");

}
```

I thought that it may be problem with `data`, but when I've changed method to call ajax function foreach `id` in `ids`, It returned same error. What do I do wrong ?

**EDIT**

I've found solution.

The problem was with Database Table, it did not have PRIMARY KEY...

Comment: What is the `Exception` in the API?

Comment: Have you investigated which error returns as 500 from the server using developer console in the browser?

Comment: A 500 error is a problem on the server, so check what the response text is and debug it. Failing that set a breakpoint in the Action, step through it, profit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the thing is it does even arrive to controller. I set breakpoint for first line in the Action, and it does not work.

Comment: In which case debug the response text of the 500 error in the network tab of the console. If you're in debug mode then you'll get a stack trace

Comment: @fanarek Can you try changing the method's input param from `List<int>` to `int[]`, and the AJAX call from `id :` to `ids :` ?

Comment: can you try to change this in ajax **data: { ids : JSON.stringify(ids) }**  and see if it works?, Actually your controller is expecting **List<int> ids** whereas you are passing id in data

Comment: @KobyDouek it did not help with problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've debugged it in the way you mentioned. It redirects to my custom 500 error page. What came to my attention was request text which looks like hieroglyphics : ids%5B%5D=2&ids%5B%5D=3&ids%5B%5D=4&ids%5B%5D=5

Comment: That's a URL encodes string. When decode it looks like this: `ids[]=2&ids[]=3&ids[]=4&ids[]=5`

Comment: also try to change **JSON.stringify(ids)** to ids only

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan HandleErrorInfo says: Invalid JSON primitive: id

Comment: In which case remove the call to `JSON.stringify()`